# “Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level”

Tags: python

can you please tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
def insert_sequence(str1, str2, index):
    '''The first two parameters are DNA sequences and the third parameter
       is an index. Return the DNA sequence obtained by inserting the second
       DNA sequence into the first DNA sequence at the given index.

       >>>insert_sequence('CCGG', 'AT',2)
       CCATGG

    '''
   str1 = str1[0:index] + str2 + str1[index:len(str1)]
   return str1
```

Answer (score 5):

Your docstring is indented one space further than the rest of the function body.  Either dedent the docstring one space or indent the rest one space (probably the latter, since that would make it four spaces, if I'm counting right).

Answer (score 0):

Python is very strict about the indentation, you therefore need to make sure all your blocks are aligned correctly, the problem here is therefore that the string is one space further than the two lines below. Make them aligned and you should be good.